# Create copy of Gson JSONElement, transforming primitive values to strings

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to make a copy of a JsonElement where all primitives are transformed to strings. All value primitives need to end up as strings.

I am reading in JSON like follows:

```
String jsonString = getData("D:/json.txt");
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement input = parser.parse(jsonString);
```

We need the input to be the above JsonElement input with primitives changed to strings. 
So the input JSON below

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    "measure" : 155
  }
}
```

And the output JsonElement would be something like

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": ["125.6", "10.1"]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    "measure" : "155"
  }
}
```

Notice that the contents of the "coordinates" array are changed from floats to strings and the value of the "measure" pair was changed from an integer to a string.

I tried iterating through JsonElement/JsonObject using JsonObject.addProperty, replacing the values with strings and am having trouble. Its hard when you get into
deep nested arrays of  objects, etc. I want to see if there is a better way (maybe using the streaming and  adapter apis?)

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A JSON string is not a JSON integer; you are doing everything to complicate things instead of simplifying them...

Comment: We have a need to do this. The contents of the JSON are returned to a Web UI (JavaScript) to be parsed and displayed as an HTML list (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp). The returned JSON is parsed by a JSON parser. Sometimes we need to throw in emphasis/bold tags in the value. "measure" : <b>155</b> is not legal JSON. "measure": "<b>155</b>" is legal JSON. We want all of the values to be strings so we can add HTML tags to the value when we need to.